# Accessing a variable's information

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am creating a tool to find the temperature of two areas in New Mexico. In the data set, there is a temperature variable inside a dictionary (`main`) that I can not seem to get the contents of for my program. The output should be `288.142` and yes I know this is in kelvins.

```
NMNorthzip=[87401,87301]

for x in NMNorthzip:
    r = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip="
                     +str(x) + ",us&appid=id")
    data = r.json()
    forecast = data['list']

    for n in forecast:
        main = n['main']
        for z in main.items():
            print(z)
```

Output:

```
('temp_max', 288.142)
('sea_level', 1028.46)
('grnd_level', 797.18)
('temp_min', 288.142)
('temp', 288.142)
('humidity', 26)
('temp_kf', 0)
('pressure', 797.18)
```

Comment: Do you mean `print(main['temp'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the dictionary to a list and printing the (key, pair) tuples resulting from the `.items()` function. So remove this:

```
    for z in main.items():
        print(z)
```

Instead access dictionary items:

```
    temperature = main['temp']
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I think I need to call it a day.